# local temporal S3 cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, caching

So the problem is as followed:

We have multiple workers that consume jobs from a sqs queue. Part of this job involves  downloading/uploading data from/to s3. Often, data uploaded by one worker will be downloaded by the next or multiple workers will download the same data. Data is only needed for a short period. When something hasn't been used in 15 minutes its not likely to be needed ever again.

What we want:

A local caching layer that sits inbetween s3 and the workers. Workers download and upload everything to the cache and the caching layer makes sure everything gets updated and that everything gets downloaded at most once. Ideally, when a file with a certain id gets updated, it will also be cached so that if another worker requests it, it will be directly available. We can assume that a file on s3 never changes (except for the first time it gets uploaded.)

My question:

I was wondering if something already exists for this? I did some research but couldn't find anything. We could develop something for this inhouse but there are quite some edge cases we'd have to take care of so it be nice if a good solution already exists.

Comment: What is your specific need to put the caching layer in front of S3? Is it because you wanting the upload/download to operate faster?

Comment: Have you considered using Amazon ElastiCache instead of Amazon S3?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The main reason is indeed to increase the performance. We often download/upload files up to 1GB which can be quite slow. Since all our workers run on the same local network caching would greatly improve the performance.
I'm not certain if ElastiCache will solve our problem since we're not dealing with a lot of small requests but few requests that load big chunks of data. We would thus want something that we can host on the local network where we run our workers.

Comment: Requests for software recommendations are off-topic for SO, but Squid Proxy might do what you want: https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/AboutSquid -- beware, though, that using a proxy with the AWS SDK is highly dependent on which SDK you're using.

Comment: What do you mean by "our workers run on the same local network"? Are your workers running in AWS (eg on EC2 instances or ECS clusters)?

Comment: our workers run on Genesis Clous